# PHP functions not giving the expected output

Tags: php, html

I am new to php so can anyone tell me why when I open the HTML, it is not showing “5! is 120” as it should be and am instead getting:

Applications

", $num, "! is ", factorial ($num), ".

"; } else { echo "

Please enter a positive integer.

"; } echo "

Return to the Entry Page

"; ?>

PHP functions

```
 <?php 
function isPositiveInteger ($n) {
    $result = false;
    if (is_numeric($n))
        if ($n == floor($n))
            if ($n>0 )
                $result = true;
            return $result;
}

function factorial ($n) {   // declare the factorial function
    $result = 1;        // declare and initialise the result variable
    $factor = $n;       // declare and initialise the factor variable
    while ($factor > 1) {   // loop to multiple all factors until 1
      $result = $result * $factor;
      $factor--;        // next factor
    }               // Note that the factor 1 is not multiplied
    return $result;
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="product" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML5, tags" />
  <meta name="author" content="Ib"  />
  <title>Product</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 <?php
 include ("mathfunctions.php");
 ?>
 <h1> Applications </h1>
 <?php
 $num=5;
 if (isPositiveInteger($num)) {
     echo "<p>", $num, "! is ", factorial ($num), ".</p>";
 } else {
    echo "<p> Please enter a positive integer. </p>";
 }
echo "<p> <a href='factorial.html'> Return to the Entry Page </a></p>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you first add a semicolon after " $num=5 " ?

Comment: Must have missed it while copying over. Edited it.

Comment: works correct for me - be it that I replaced the include( ) with a definition of the functions themselves. What version PHP are you running ? I can't find it - but if memory serves me right, include( ) used to be done as one of the first lines of a script to avoid problems; not sure if this is creating your problems. Do your webserver logs indicate a PHP error ?